# iPhone hiding StatusBar shifts view down by 20 pix

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view laid out in the interface builder. Originally it used a StatusBar added to the top of the view in the interface builder. Now I decided to get rid of the status bar, but when I call

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

My view is still shifted down by 20 points. My guess is that my UINavigationController does not get the message and keeps my view in the old location.

Anyone else has an insight into what might be causing this issue?

I tried:

```
 self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y-21); This does not work.
```

I've tried:

```
   self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y-21);
```

This works, but leaves a black 20 px bar on the buttom before the tabbar.

How would I transition my view to a status-bar-less mode without having to manualy adjust all the views by 21px?

PS. The view is displayed perfectly if I remove the status bar in the app delegate before creating a UINavigationController for the view

Comment: What's the difference between those last two code snippets?

Comment: did you change the height in your xib?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subview shifting down 20 pixels when called in AppDelegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231719/subview-shifting-down-20-pixels-when-called-in-appdelegate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to call

```
[myViewController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

That should allow it to take up the spare 20px.

Comment: This appears to be what I was looking for!

Comment: Note you may need to use this option even if you have a status bar: If you have VCs which are contained within subviews on another VC, without this option ticked, IB seems to think these child VCs' views need 20pt of padding too.  In this case, "Wants Full Screen" also means "Fills enter containment view".  Hope this helps someone...

Comment: Hari is right. Atleast for myself. This is what I needed to to. The defect I was seeing was the navigation bar not shifting up 20px after hiding the statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

Interface builder has a 'simulate user interface elements' option. Do you still have 'status bar' simulated? You need to deslect that option if your actual view doesn't show a status bar.

Comment: I've deselected that option, but the view is still messed up.