# Gap when changed of viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, behavior

I'm implementing an application, in which i use several view controllers. But i've found a strange behaviour of my app' when it changes of viewcontroller. Let me explain :

We are in a first viewcontroller, his init method is :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        Menu = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.view addSubview:Menu];
        [Menu release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

After that, to change of viewcontroller and pass from the first to another, i call this method :

```
-(void)GoPlay
{
    if (!parametresviewcontroller)
    {
        parametresviewcontroller = [[ParametresViewController alloc]init];
    }
    UIView *menuView = menuviewcontroller.view;
    UIView *paramView = parametresviewcontroller.view;

    [menuviewcontroller viewWillAppear:NO];
    [parametresviewcontroller viewWillDisappear:NO];
    [menuView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:paramView];
    [menuviewcontroller viewDidAppear:NO];
    [parametresviewcontroller viewDidDisappear:NO];
}
```

So the init method of the second viewcontroller is called, i put it next :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        Parametres = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
        Parametres.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.view addSubview:Parametres];
        [Parametres release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And the result is :

[image: Result of changing]

Why this strange behavior occured ? I really don't understand why the is a gap between the first and the second one...
Thank you ! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, The problem is, both the class Is a `UIViewController` and you have set `statusbar` for both `ViewController`'s `View` in `XIB` file. When you set StatusBar Than the view frame changes its y to 20 pixel below means you have set it to 0 but originally it is 20.

> So when you add `subView` second `ViewController`'s view on the first `ViewController`'s View before doing this set:
>    secondViewController.view.frame = firstViewController.view.bounds;
>   . This will solve your problem.

Comment: I have seen that the frame changes of 20 pixels, but don't know why, and your solution is really helpfull. Really thanks guy, i now know where did it comes !

Comment: The problem is, it not respond to any event now on the second view controller :/

Comment: Don't know how to fix this error, after i put paramView.frame = menuView.bounds; as you said, no elements responds to clicks (UIButtons...)

Comment: ok don't do any thing with frame, just set set statusBar is non for secondView controller before addSubview it, Or you can set it by XIB also if it does not require other places.

Comment: If you have big issue. send me these files, will try to fix it

Comment: But how could i set the status bar by the code hidden for one view controller ? :s

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

Comment: Sorry, skip my prev comment. Go to second viewcontroller's XIB file. Select View and set it's statusBar property non

Comment: But i don't use XIB files, that's while i don't know how to do it by the code :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31659/discussion-between-prateek-prem-and-user2057209)

Comment: Found the solution, see one answer which is possible =) But thanks guy

Answer (score 0):

First of all, DO NOT CALL `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` by yourself, this methods are called by the OS in some specific points of a `UIViewController` life-cycle.

Second, `initWithNibName` is not the proper method for adding subviews to the controller's view, for that you should use `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad`.

Third, what you are doing is not `changing of view controllers` is simply adding a view controller's view to another view controller view, for changing `UIViewController` you should use `addChildViewController:` and `removeFromParentViewController` methods or use `UINavigationController`

Comment: Don't think that it's the best answer, the other is. But thank you for the help !

Comment: I think my answer should have been a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution : [iPhone hiding StatusBar shifts view down by 20 pix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275699/iphone-hiding-statusbar-shifts-view-down-by-20-pix)

Use 
    [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
in the init method in my case.

Thank you all !